# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find sun.misc.Unsafe while @MockK

Tags: kotlin, junit5, java-11, mockk

I'm having an issue when creating a mock using MockK.
I have tried with kotlin 1.2.* version with MockK without Kotlin 1.3 but it also didn't help.

How can I resolve this? Is this because of OpenJDK 11 of it's something else?

Java version:

```
openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.3.0-rc-190'
        springBootVersion = '2.0.6.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

group 'org.group'
version '0.0.1'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {

    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive')

    implementation('com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin')
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")

    testCompile('io.mockk:mockk:1.8.9.kotlin13')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.0')
    testImplementation('io.projectreactor:reactor-test')
    testImplementation('de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:2.1.1')
}

configurations.all {
    exclude group: "org.mockito", module: "mockito-core"
}

sourceCompatibility = 11
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

HistoryClient:

```
interface AccountHistoryClient
```

Test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockKExtension::class)
internal class ReactiveLoadTransactionsHandlerTest {

    @MockK
    lateinit var historyClient: historyClient
    @InjectMockKs
    lateinit var handler: Handler

    @Test
    fun handle() {
    }
}
```

When I run this test I get this error

```
    io.mockk.MockKException: Can't instantiate proxy for class com.group.HistoryClient

    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactory.newProxy(JvmMockFactory.kt:64)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.AbstractMockFactory.newProxy$default(AbstractMockFactory.kt:28)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.AbstractMockFactory.mockk(AbstractMockFactory.kt:53)
    at io.mockk.impl.annotations.JvmMockInitializer.assignMockK(JvmMockInitializer.kt:145)
    at io.mockk.impl.annotations.JvmMockInitializer.initMock(JvmMockInitializer.kt:39)
    at io.mockk.impl.annotations.JvmMockInitializer.initAnnotatedMocks(JvmMockInitializer.kt:22)
    at io.mockk.junit5.MockKExtension.postProcessTestInstance(MockKExtension.kt:107)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$null$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:204)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:145)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$3(ClassTestDescriptor.java:204)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassTestDescriptor.java:203)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:189)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$1(ClassTestDescriptor.java:181)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:80)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.prepare(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:89)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: io.mockk.proxy.MockKAgentException: Failed to subclass interface com.vegesoft.moneytracker.statistics.client.AccountHistoryClient
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.ProxyMaker.proxy(ProxyMaker.kt:38)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactory.newProxy(JvmMockFactory.kt:34)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:140)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:161)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.transformation.SubclassInstrumentation.subclass(SubclassInstrumentation.kt:46)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.ProxyMaker.subclass(ProxyMaker.kt:110)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.ProxyMaker.proxy(ProxyMaker.kt:35)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot define class using reflection
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$Unavailable.defineClass(ClassInjector.java:821)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection.inject(ClassInjector.java:185)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default$InjectionDispatcher.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:187)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy$Passive.initialize(TypeResolutionStrategy.java:79)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:4457)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.transformation.SubclassInstrumentation.doInterceptedSubclassing(SubclassInstrumentation.kt:80)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.transformation.SubclassInstrumentation.access$doInterceptedSubclassing(SubclassInstrumentation.kt:17)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.transformation.SubclassInstrumentation$subclass$1.call(SubclassInstrumentation.kt:49)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.transformation.SubclassInstrumentation$subclass$1.call(SubclassInstrumentation.kt:17)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:138)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find sun.misc.Unsafe
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingUnsafe$Dispatcher$Disabled.initialize(ClassInjector.java:1366)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingUnsafe.inject(ClassInjector.java:1202)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$ForUnsafeInjection.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:458)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy$Passive.initialize(TypeResolutionStrategy.java:79)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:4457)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$Indirect.make(ClassInjector.java:684)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$CreationAction.run(ClassInjector.java:302)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$CreationAction.run(ClassInjector.java:290)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection.<clinit>(ClassInjector.java:70)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default$InjectionDispatcher.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:184)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String, [B, int, int, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.security.ProtectionDomain)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2109)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingUnsafe$Dispatcher$CreationAction.run(ClassInjector.java:1269)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingUnsafe$Dispatcher$CreationAction.run(ClassInjector.java:1257)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingUnsafe.<clinit>(ClassInjector.java:1136)
    ... 85 more
```

Comment: `Unsafe#defineClass` was removed in Java 11 : https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8199699

Comment: https://github.com/mockk/mockk so it does not have Java 11 support like in description?

Comment: I was porting it to Java 11 and everyting was OK https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/150

Comment: Issue can happen if something is overriding ByteBuddy version. Check one you have in dependency tree and one supplied with mockk

Comment: Unfortunately the only thing providing ByteBuddy is `mockk` itself `net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.8.22 -> 1.7.11`

I have overrided byte-buddy to version `1.8.22` and it started to work. I'm not gradle expert but it seems like in my case for some reason byte-buddy is being downgraded to `1.7.11`. I have no idea why

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to follow the answer from @lukaszrys I had this exact problem with running Mockito under Java 11. I was using Gradle and adding the following to my `dependencies` fixed it for me:

```
testCompile "net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.8.22"
testCompile "net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.8.22"
```

Comment: I'd expect more recent builds of Mockito to just work. I've had no special need to add byte buddy stuff via gradle in the last couple of years.

Answer (score 1):

One of the included dependencies was downgrading byte-buddy to version `1.7.11` (as pointed by oleksiyp).

I have manually included byte-buddy with version `1.8.22` and it started to work.

Comment: Damn, it wasn't really too obvious in my case... Huge thanks for the tip!